# Gyms in South Korea

Tags: south-korea

I am planning to visit South Korea (Seoul) a few times this year (so I can learn the language). Each stay can vary from 1 to 2 weeks.

Despite the break however I'd like to be able to work out while I am there.

Does anyone know if commonly in SK you can buy short gym membership or just pay as you go?

Comment: You did not mention where you are gonna stay. It could help us in refining the answer. Are you gonna stay at different places each time?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed I've just mentioned in the post.

Comment: Note that some hotels have gyms too

Comment: @xuq01 but I want to find a good combination to save money. Being aware of alternatives is therefore useful

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine used to go to the YMCA, on Jongno I believe, which had a gym where you paid as you went. There a YWCA too, in Myeongdong.